# How to configure apache 2.2 to allow acme-challenge and pass all other traffic to AJP/tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, tomcat

GOAL: To configure a server to perform automated SLL certs renewal via acme-protocol ( Using dehydrated https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated ) with apache 2.2 / tomcat

Work for automated cert renewal already functioning for a virt eth0 ( bound to a unique IP )

Need to be able to allow http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ to perform domain challenge, while passing everything else off to AJP/Tomcat

iptables

Looked at the following resources in my search - it seems like multiple proxypass's may be the way to go, but I'm not sure.

Configure Apache with multiple ProxyPass
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914235/configure-apache-with-multiple-proxypass

This question seems to be similar to what I'm doing, but didn't generate traction.

How to configure Apache 2.2 to forward all subdomains to Tomcat except the root domain
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081145/how-to-configure-apache-2-2-to-forward-all-subdomains-to-tomcat-except-the-root

```
=========================

Existing apache2 config


    ServerName myserver.example.com/
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /Application
    
        #ProxyRequests Off
        #ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass ajp://127.0.0.1:8009 keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse http://Application/example.com/
            #ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
    
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/Application-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/Application-access.log combined


=========================

What I think a good config is going to look like ( unsure of values to acually use with proxypass )


    ServerName myserver.example.com/
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /Application
    
            ProxyPass
        ProxyPassReverse
            ProxyPass
        ProxyPassReverse http://Application/example.com/
            #ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
    
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/openkm-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/openkm-access.log combined


=========================
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a line like this

```
ProxyPass /.well-known/acme-challenge !
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009 keepalive=On
```

This will prevent the acme-challenge request to be passed to the Tomcat.

And of course, you need to have the DocumentRoot configured properly to point to whatever folder contains your acme challenges.